# Return an error message from a TRIGGER in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, exception, triggers, postgresql-8.4

I want to perform some business validation of the data being inserted in a table and I need to check data in another table when doing so. The way to this seems to be using a `BEFORE INSERT FOR EACH ROW TRIGGER` in PostgreSQL and from the function it calls I can return NULL if the new data fails validation to prevent it being inserted.

Is there any way I can return an error message describing the validation error as well?

Comment: In addition to @mu's answer, [consider this](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/7214/3684) if you want a *context* for your own exceptions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`raise`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) for exceptions:

> **39.8. Errors and Messages**
>
> Use the `RAISE` statement to report messages and raise errors.
>   [...]
>   `EXCEPTION` raises an error (which normally aborts the current transaction);

So you can say things like this in your trigger:

```
raise exception 'Say something useful about %', some_variable;
```

That will abort the trigger and (usually) the current transaction. The message that you raise should make its way back to the client application.

Comment: careful, you can't use NOTIFY in a trigger if there's an exception